# how to save the value of an element on state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table that renders `patientInfo array`. Then I have a `countDown component` that counts downs starting from 15mins. This countDown renders when the `patient.locationInfo` column and `patient.obsDetail` column isn't empty. So each patient row has individual countDown counting down from 15mins. What I need to do is save the coundown on state because when the countDown gets to 14mins, I need to disable buttons on `Patient Location` column. I'm not sure how to execute this. I thought of onChange event, but it doesn't work as 
I'm not working with input/form alike elements. I can get the time displayed by `document.getElementById('count-down').textContent` but I can't set the time to state with componentDidUpdate as it throws multiple setState errors.

```
getTime = (data) => {
        const countDown = document.getElementById('count-down'); 

        if(countDown !== null){

            this.setState(prevState => ({ patientInfo:
                   prevState.patientInfo.map((patient, i) => {
                if (i === index) {
                    return { ...patient, obsDue: countDown.textContent };
                }
                return patient;
            }) 
       }));
    }

componentDidUpdate() {
     this.getTime(); // throws error 
   }
```

```
    <td id='countDownTime'>{patient.locationInfo !== '' && patient.obsDetail !== '' ?  <countDown /> : ''} </td>
```

[image]

Comment: There is no change event on table cell data.

Comment: The signature is `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`, and you can simply compare `prevState.countDown` to `this.state.countDown`